# Highest count in a data frame pandas

Tags: pandas, count, google-colaboratory, multiple-columns

I'm trying to extract 10 columns from a csv file with pandas in Google colab so I'm using this line `firstten = data.iloc[:, 0:10] # first ten columns of data frame with all rows`

After that I used `firstten.count()` to count the number of values in each column so after that what I want to know is that if in one of those columns have 80 different values and the others are lower I want to know from this ten columns the highest number of counts for that, I used the `max` but it didn't work some help with this please I don't need to know which column just the number in some pieces of data will be repeated 80 like 4 times so also to have this in mind with the solution. Also I thought about using the sort function but maybe there is another option.

Thanks for your help this is the output that I would like to get:
[image]

Comment: I think you want to know the `value_counts` of each column.   Look at pd.Series.value_counts.   Add some some sample data and expected output to this question and we can help you with code.

Comment: @ScottBoston I added the expected output in the image, thanks

Comment: `firstten.count().max()` will return 10 in this case.

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks that works and to see the columns only with that values?

Comment: Try `firstten.columns[firstten.count() == firstten.count().max()]`

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks that work, but now if I want to get the values in the colums for those I have to use iloc?

Comment: Yes.  Use .loc. That will work.

Comment: Let's try this, `dfm.count()[dfm.count() == dfm.count().max()]` you don't need loc.  If I understand your question correclty.

Comment: What I needed was this `columnstwo = columns.to_list()` then `data.loc[:, columnstwo]`